Why my Ruby on Rails app is no longer working as a development environment?
I am building a pet project on Ruby on Rails and I wanted to add some Javascript and React.
I did a base with Rails and SCSS.
When I added some sound with Javascript, it wasn't working so I tried chatgpt and suggested this rake:assets:recompile on my terminal. That didn't work at first and then I had to:
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and change the version and do again the recompile command. And it worked.
But after this, I messed up my config somehow and now everytime I modify my SCSS and I refresh (or hard-refresh) it's not working but if I do rake:assets:recompile and restart the server and it works(i can see the SCSS  changes).
This is very annoying and I don't know what to do, so it behaves like a development environment.
Please help :)
I already tried so many things.
I also tried going back to the master of the project, but it still doesn't work.

There should be no need to precompile/recompile assets in development. Try removing all of the compiled assets using bundle exec rails assets:clobber
